# How to know the location of file from url?

Tags: debugging, fiddler

What I want to know is how to know which file is being called to render the webpage

i.e., for example I am visiting an url: http://local-servername/abc/0/86#Create

the page is loading fine but what I should know is from which code is being called and how the page is loading
I am using fiddler to get that info but I am unable get the file names and location.

please suggest how to use fiddler or is there any other tools for this

thanks in advance